# Extract float based on condition applied to string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called country_data with two columns, country (string) and population density (float), and would like to find the population density for a chosen country.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
Country       Population Density
Albania            124.6
Algeria             13.8
Andorra            152.1
```

I have tried the following query, but it just produces an object:

```
country_data.loc[country_data["Country"] == country, "Population Density"]
```

How can I extract a population density value?

Comment: country_data.loc[country_data["Country"] == country]["Population Density"]

Comment: The variable *country* is not defined. Your query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `.values[0]` to access the first value of the Series. So:

```
country_data.loc[country_data["Country"] == country, "Population Density"].values[0]
```